# Assign single output for multiple-output function to new function

Tags: r, function, plot, output

I have a function that gives me a single output which is however composed of two elements. Example for it would be:

```
example <- function(x){
  sin <- sin(x)
  cos <- cos(x)
  output <- cbind(sin, cos)
  return(output)
}
```

Now my idea is to plot separately sin and cos, each as functions of x. I would like to avoid writing a separate function in this context since the two objects are better to be calculated all at once.
If I try :

```
x_grid = seq(0,1,0,0.05)
plot(x_grid, sapply(x_grid, FUN = example[1]))
```

I get the following error message :

> Error in example[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

How to proceed then? (notice that I use `sapply` because I need my function to deal with more than a single value of x in my real case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be an extra parameter to `seq`

```
x_grid <- seq(0, 1, 0.05)
```

Slight modification to pass variable to function and then subset

```
plot(x_grid, sapply(x_grid, function(x) example(x)[1]))
```

Another approach for function which uses a list and then the function can be subset by name

```
example2 <- function(x) {
  within(list(), {
    sin <- sin(x)
    cos <- cos(x)
  })
}

plot(x_grid, sapply(x_grid, function(x) example2(x)$sin))
```

Unless the example is simplified, the following works without `sapply`

```
plot(x_grid, example2(x_grid)$sin)
```

Plotting both results

```
lapply(example2(x_grid), plot, x_grid)
```

Comment: your second line did the job. Simple and effective!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a non-base graphics solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
example3 <- function(x){
  data.frame(
    x = x,
    sin = sin(x),
    cos = cos(x)
  )
}

x_grid=seq(0,1,0.05)
ggplot(data = example3(x_grid),
       aes(x=x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sin), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = cos), color = "red")
```

With the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function is vectorized so you can input a vector and extract each column by `example(x_grid)[, "sin"]` or `example(x_grid)[, "cos"]`.

```
example(x_grid)
#                 sin          cos
#   [1,]  0.000000000  1.000000000
#   [2,]  0.049979169  0.998750260
#   [3,]  0.099833417  0.995004165
```

```
example(x_grid)[, "sin"]

# [1]  0.000000000  0.049979169  0.099833417  0.149438132  0.198669331
# [6]  0.247403959  0.295520207  0.342897807  0.389418342  0.434965534
```

**Note:** In this case, `sapply` is not recommended because the function itself has been vectorized. `sapply` will make it inefficient. Here is an illustration by benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  basic = example(x_grid)[, 1],
  sapply = sapply(x_grid, function(x) example(x)[1]),
  times = 1000L
)
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

---

If you want to plot both the two functions, `matplot()` can plot each column of one matrix.

```
x_grid <- seq(0, 10, 0.05)
matplot(x_grid, example(x_grid), type = "l")
```

[image]